# How can I add a menu dynamically to bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, android-view, bottomnavigationview

Android has new ui element - BottomNavigationView

[image]

I don't want to contain my menus in the xml files. I will receive the information about menu items and order from backend side. I want to create them dynamically and set into the `BottomNavigationView` in the `onCreate()` method. Can I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default, `BottomNavigationView` starts with an empty menu. You can use the [`getMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#getMenu()) method to get the Menu instance, then add menu items as in the [response above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41345167/404597). For example,

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
Menu menu = bottomNavigation.getMenu();
menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_ONE, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.str_menu_one))
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_one);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a tint color list also, when creating menuitem like this? I'm currently struggling to set a tin color list for the items' icons and text

Comment: @kdas I know this is late, but do that in the xml layout for the bottom nav view using app:itemIconTint

Answer (score 16):

The easy way to use dynamic options in bottom navigation view is use different menu items like this:

```
switch (userType){
            case UserTypes.A:
                bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation_a);
                break;
            case UserTypes.B:
                bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation_b);
                break;
            case UserTypes.C:
                bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_navigation_c);
               break;
        }
```

Comment: Question is how to make menu items dynamically, for e.g at runtime. Your solution still means app should have above 3 types of menu available

Answer (score 5):

Heres an example of dynamic build of menu items, in the main activity u have 2 layouts.
you can get your own layout from your backend and create menu items dynamically using menu.add

src: http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2014/01/dynamically-create-menu-items-in-android.html

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button mButtonOne,mButtonTwo;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_ONE =1;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_TWO =2;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_THREE =3;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_FOUR =4;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_FIVE =5;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID_SIX =6;
private int mMenuSet = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mButtonOne=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetOne);
    mButtonTwo=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetTwo);

    mButtonOne.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    mButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
OnClickListener clickListener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonSetOne) {
            mMenuSet=1;
        } else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonSetTwo){
            mMenuSet=2;
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        /*
         * if you are using ActionBarSherlock use this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
         * if you are using ActionBarCompat use invalidateOptionsMenu (Activity activity) method
         * */
    }
};
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    if(mMenuSet==1){
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_ONE, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_one)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_one).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_TWO, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_two)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_two).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_THREE, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_three)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_three);

    }else if(mMenuSet==2){
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_FOUR, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_four)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_four).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_FIVE, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_five)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_five).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM_ID_SIX, Menu.NONE,getString(R.string.str_menu_six)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_six);
    }       
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_ONE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_one), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_TWO:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_two), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_THREE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_three), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_FOUR:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_four), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_FIVE:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_five), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM_ID_SIX:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.str_menu_six), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click on "+ getString(R.string.action_settings), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Comment: did you get any solution ??

Comment: Well.. It works... but how to bind click listener to it? Please make clear this detail and you will get +1 more, dude! :)

Comment: to which view? 
if it's for one of the bottom buttons you can see the click listener in the onCreate method (in the example it is changing the menu set, you can perform more actions after).
if it's for the menu items you can see the click listener in onOptionsItemSelected method, you can change it to whatever you want.