# Add Textview in bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

It seems Bottom navigation view can only accept a drawable icon and not plain textview as an icon for navigation. What I want to achieve is to add textview that would have user ititial and a circle background. Would greatly appreciate your help

[image]

Is there an alternative

Comment: refer this link ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861254/how-to-change-a-specific-icon-image-from-bottom-navigation-view

Comment: The initial is dynamic, will depend on user's name, hence not possible in xml as suggested by the link you shared. thanks @Manikandan

Comment: refer this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345006/how-can-i-add-a-menu-dynamically-to-bottom-navigation-view  ..instead of add icon (R.drawable.icon) use (selector refer previous link)..